# Put link in message body sent with Mailgun?

Tags: mailgun

Im using Mailgun to send emails with this function on my node server.

The link to my site is coming out as plain text rather than a clickable link. How can I make the link be an actual href in the email?

```
const emailWelcome = ({ name, email }) => {
  const data = {
    from: 'James <james@example.com>',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Welcome to My Site',
    text: `Hi ${name},

    Welcome to <a href="http://example.com/">My Site</a>

    James
    `,
  };

  mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for `mailgun-js` it says:

> Sending messages in MIME format can be accomplished using the
> sendMime() function of the messages() proxy object.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js#sending-mime-messages

The documentation then provides this code example:

```
var domain = 'mydomain.org';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey: "YOUR API KEY", domain: domain });
var MailComposer = require('nodemailer/lib/mail-composer');
 
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'you@samples.mailgun.org',
  to: 'mm@samples.mailgun.org',
  subject: 'Test email subject',
  text: 'Test email text',
  html: '<b> Test email text </b>'
};
 
var mail = new MailComposer(mailOptions);
 
mail.compile().build((err, message) => {
 
    var dataToSend = {
        to: 'mm@samples.mailgun.org',
        message: message.toString('ascii')
    };
 
    mailgun.messages().sendMime(dataToSend, (sendError, body) => {
        if (sendError) {
            console.log(sendError);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

At the time of sharing this, the current version is `0.20.0`.

As the code demonstrates, with a multi-part message you will need to provide both a plain text and HTML version of the message.

Comment: Thanks for this, the answer is still valid for `mailgun.js@4.1.4`. Just add the `html` field.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com#create